# Make [orange-san-francisco] and [dell-xcd35] synonyms of [zte-blade]

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

I just created the latter two tags.  The devices seem to be most commonly known as the [zte-blade](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zte-blade) so I propose that as the parent.  There is little to no difference between it and the [orange-san-francisco](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/orange-san-francisco) or the [dell-xcd35](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dell-xcd35), from what I can tell, so it's probably useful to group them together as synonyms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZTE_Blade says they're the same. I'll create synonyms.

***Update***: This is now complete.